# How to resolve the terraform error "timeout while waiting for state to become 'done: true' (last state: 'done: false', timeout: 10m0s)"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a Firestore index using terraform in GCP.
Below is my Terraform script:

```
resource "google_firestore_index" "job_config1_index" {
  project = var.projectId

  collection = var.job_config_firestore
  depends_on = [
    "google_firestore_index.job_config4_index"
  ]

  fields {
    field_path = "customer_id"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "job_type"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "start_date_time"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "__name__"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }
}
```

Below are the logs:

```
Step #2: Error: Error waiting to create Index: Error waiting for Creating Index: timeout while waiting for state to become 'done: true' (last state: 'done: false', timeout: 10m0s)
Step #2: 
Step #2:   on firestore.tf line 298, in resource "google_firestore_index" "job_config1_index":
Step #2:  298: resource "google_firestore_index" "job_config1_index" {
Step #2: 
Step #2:
```

My other Firestore indexes are creating fine.
How can I increase the timeout for each index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some resources, including the `google_firestore_index` resource, have optionally configurable timeouts for creation, updates and/or deletes using the [`timeouts` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#operation-timeouts):

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  # ...

  timeouts {
    create = "60m"
    delete = "2h"
  }
}
```

So in your case you would add a `create` timeout to the Firestore index like this:

```
resource "google_firestore_index" "job_config1_index" {
  project = var.projectId

  collection = var.job_config_firestore
  depends_on = [
    "google_firestore_index.job_config4_index"
  ]

  fields {
    field_path = "customer_id"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "job_type"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "start_date_time"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  fields {
    field_path = "__name__"
    order      = "ASCENDING"
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "60m"
  }
}
```